# How to override the attribution of an auto incrementing primary key when inserting a value in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table of users whose **primary key is an auto-incrementing integer**. The table is already populated with records whose key is between 0 and 30.000. Not all records are there, though. Some users have been removed and therefore I have "holes".

Now the client has realised they removed a bunch of users by mistake, and they now want me to reinsert those users keeping the same ID they had, for compatibility with the back-end of the e-commerce, which runs on a different machine altogether, but uses the same ID's for the customers.

At the moment I am:

1. altering the structure of the table, by removing the auto_increment property from the ID
2. adding the records I need, specifying their ID
3. reverting the alterations to the structure of the table.

**Is there a better way to achieve this? Is there any SQL `override` function that would allow me to force MySQL to accept a value that is unique but not necessarily "the next number in the line"?**

Comment: Not an answer to the problem here, but a very important note:
In order to avoid accidentally deleting records, never actually delete the record.  Set a field such as `isActive` or `deleted` or `archived` or something of that nature to false (or true, whichever makes sense).  And when you pull records, only pull records that are marked as active.  That way mistakes like this become easy to fix.  And it's a more robust and versatile system.
(Non-important note: I came here looking for ways I could auto-increment at like 1000 and insert the important records where I want them.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't have to disable the `auto_increment` feature. When you insert a row into the table and you do specify the primary key value in the row, the id you want is stored in the database. The `auto_increment` is only used, when you omit the primary key field.

EDIT: I thought I might give examples for that:

```
mysql> describe test;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test (value) values ('row 1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | row 1 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (15, 'row 2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | row 1 |
| 15 | row 2 |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
mysql> insert into test (id, value) values (3, 'row 3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | row 1 |
| 15 | row 2 |
|  3 | row 3 |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just realised that this works only when you manually set a "id" that is greater than the greatest "id" already in the table. The method fails if you try to assign a "id" which is not existent in the table but is lower than the greatest already inserted... :-/

Comment: Thank you for having got back to me. I checked by following your "tutorial" and I can manage. I will test on the original DB on which I failed and will report back. It might take a few days, though.

Comment: If you try to insert zero "0" in the auto-inc field mysql (at least the one instance I tried on 5.7.19 ) thinks that value is not set and uses the auto-inc instead.

Comment: Does the "next id" get set automatically or something? What's going to happen next time I insert a row without specifying an ID?

Comment: @DanSoap: It only works if the higher IDs weren't generated via auto_increment. You cannot insert an explicit ID that is less-or-equals to the largest AI-generated id. That value can be found in select AUTO_INCREMENT from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabase' AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable'.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund thanks for pointing out that 0 means increment. Or you can disable that feature with this big ugly hammer [`SET sql_mode="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero)

Comment: @erict Actually you can, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b03148/1 . The downside though is that every time you manually insert an id which is larger than the current auto_increment value, the AI value is set to the just inserted value.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  I discovered that you can set the ID to any number in an update, although you can't set it below the current minimum in an insert.  To get around this I wrote a script that converted my import data into a series of SQL statements, with a pair  that resembled the following for each row of data:

```
// This inserts the record with the next auto_increment id<br />
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, NAME, OTHER_COL...) VALUES (17, 'UNIQUE VALUE', 'other value'...);<br />
// This sets the correct ID on the newly inserted record<br />
UPDATE mytable SET ID=17 WHERE NAME='UNIQUE VALUE';
```

If you don't have a unique field, then you might write a SQL to get the largest ID and update that to the correct ID before inserting the next record. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid problems with the implementation of AUTO_INCREMENT (or identity fields in any database), I never use it when something outside the database (either a person or a system) has to know about the values.

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) says:

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be
>   used to generate a unique identity for
>   new rows.

In my opinion, that's all you should care about.  The numbers are there and they are unique.  Never mind what they are and if they have "gaps" or "holes".  If you want externally-visible IDs, maybe some kind of GUID would be better.

Comment: This is not really an answer... but thank you anyway for the tip! (+1) Philosophically I agree with you, and would use an "adapter pattern" to do what you suggest. The history of legacies of this particular project however ruled that option out.

Comment: That's understandable.  My hands are often tied when working on legacy systems.  Hopefully other people will see this and save themselves a minor headache.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, that the driver you use reads the table schema and adapts to it. When it sees `auto_increment` column it skips its value. This is the case with C# `DataAdapter`, like in [Generating insert statement that includes identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17951683/772981).

As they say `DataAdapter` cannot be configured and the only option is to use manual `insert` command.

Answer (score 0):

I found this here because i have the same problem.
Even this is older, maybee it helps someone.

The auto-increment only takes effect on NEW inserted roles.
It not possible to set a new role with a given value that is lower than the currently highest increment-value in the table.

To solve this problem, just insert a new row (and let the auto-increment set a value) afterwards just change this value!
(if the value is not in used, it will work)

untestet:
maybe it could also solve the problem if you reset the auto-increment-counter