# Generating insert statement that includes identity column

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to use CommandBuilder to generate an insert statement that includes an Identity column. For test data generation purposes I want to be able to insert a value into the identity column after Identity Insert has been enabled on the table

```
var sql = "Select * from Table";
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
dataAdapter.Fill(currentTable);
var cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
```

The command builder does generate the insert statement, but I can't get it to include the identity column. I am creating a generic solution for many tables, so I want to avoid generating the statements manually. Is there a way to trick it to include all columns?

I am also open to other solutions that doesn't include CommandBuilder

Answer (score 0):

commandbuilder uses schema obtained from database, and command building process is not configurable. only option could be something like replace "instert into(" with  "insert into(id, " and "values (" with "values (@id, ". dont forget to add @id paramter to the parameter collection too.

Answer (score 0):

Use pure SQL to do this:

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON;

insert into dbo.MyTable (id, ...) values (1, ...)
...

set IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF;
```

Comment: I want to avoid this approach as since it means that I have to manually build the inserts

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by "manually build". Are you opposed to using c# string manipulation to "build" an SQL insert statement, potentially in a loop, that will be used in an `SqlCommand`?